# Can't install extension through composer

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm

If I try to install a new extension, from PHPStorm or command line, I get this error:

NOTE: I disabled the xdebug extension on my php but the warning is still showing app.

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe
>   C:\wamp\www\calificaciones\composer.phar require
>   2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget:1.0.5 -n --no-progress You are running
>   composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime
>   performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug The
>   "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" plugin requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0,
>   this *WILL* break in the future and it should be fixed ASAP (require
>   ^1.0 for example).
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks()
>   in
>   C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php
>   on line 272
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0133     422128   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\calificaciones\composer.phar:0
>       0.0136     424928   2. require('phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/bin/composer')
>   C:\wamp\www\calificaciones\composer.phar:25
>       0.1172    4937560   3. Composer\Console\Application->run() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
>       0.1246    5384936   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:99
>       0.1275    5544264   5. Composer\Console\Application->doRun() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
>       0.1341    5707456   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:166
>       0.1347    5707904   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
>       0.1348    5708432   8. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
>       0.1386    5715824   9. Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
>       0.1430    5800904  10. Composer\Command\BaseCommand->getComposer() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:97
>       0.1431    5801144  11. Composer\Console\Application->getComposer() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/BaseCommand.php:53
>       0.1431    5801224  12. Composer\Factory::create() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:244
>       0.1431    5802304  13. Composer\Factory->createComposer() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Factory.php:532
>       0.4445   10944592  14. Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->loadInstalledPlugins()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Factory.php:354
>       0.4919   11465248  15. Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->loadRepository()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php:79
>       0.4920   11465248  16. Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->registerPackage()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php:240
>       0.4981   11556808  17. Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin() phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php:188
>       0.4982   11557160  18. Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\FxpAssetPlugin->activate()
>   phar://C:/wamp/www/calificaciones/composer.phar/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php:215
>       0.4996   11626888  19. Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter->__construct()
>   C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\FxpAssetPlugin.php:90
>       0.5007   11636056  20. Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter->initialize()
>   C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php:77
>       0.5016   11659224  21. Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter->initInstalledPackages()
>   C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php:259

What is going wrong?

Comment: 1) Make sure that you have latest composer version 2) if it still display message about xdebug then you did not deactivate it completely/properly.

Comment: I have the latest, I made composer self-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks()

This indicates that there is a problem with the `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin"` plugin.

> in C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php on line 272

Since the path begins with `C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming`, it means that you installed that plugin globally.

You can update this plugin with this method [shared by the maintainer of this plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/issues/191#issuecomment-188669646):

> Update the composer and global dependencies without plugin option:
>
> ```
> $ composer selfupdate
> $ composer global update --no-plugins
> ```
>
> If you still have an error is that the plugin is not the last vresion:
>
> ```
> $ composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:"^1.1.0" --no-plugins
> ```

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall Xdebug and all config for this.
- Erase all the vendor in your `composer.json` without strictly package for your framework.
- clear your framework cache.
- update your `composer.lock`.
- you can also reinstall your basic package framework (upgrade or downgrade the version and after re-insert the package as you want).

Comment: Note that the error does not come from a framework but from a globally installed package: *Fatal error: Call to undefined method Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks() in C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php on line 272*